# Setting on click function in tabla data <td> with parameters

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, html-table

I have this code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ArregloNombres.length; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    for (var j = 0; j < ArregloNombres[i].length; j++) {
        var td = document.createElement("td");
        var text = document.createTextNode(ArregloNombres[i][j]);
        td.appendChild(text);

        tr.appendChild(td);

    }
    var Link = document.createElement("a");


    var textLink = document.createTextNode("Eliminar");


    Link.appendChild(textLink);
    Link.onclick = function() {
        eliminarImpuesto(i)
    };


    var tdLink = document.createElement("td");

    tdLink.appendChild(Link);

    tr.appendChild(tdLink);

    tabla.appendChild(tr);

}
```

where `eliminarImpuesto(i)` is just `alert(i)`. The problem is that for each link I create the same parameter is passed and it's the amount of values inside the array. For example I have two elements in the array, then the every link in the table calls the function `eliminarImpuesto(2)`, instead of sending the proper value. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "i" appears to be global. Check the link below:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_closures.asp

Maybe if you assign an attribute to your element and then get it back, you  may solve it.

```
for(var i = 0; i<ArregloNombres.length ; i++){
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
         for(var j = 0; j<ArregloNombres[i].length; j++) {
                   var td = document.createElement("td");
                   var text = document.createTextNode(ArregloNombres[i][j]);
                   td.appendChild(text);

                   tr.appendChild(td);

                 }
                   var Link = document.createElement("a");


                   var textLink = document.createTextNode("Eliminar");
                        //HERE: passing the attribute to  your element...

                        textLink.setAttribute('data-i',i);

                   Link.appendChild(textLink);
                   Link.onclick =function(){eliminarImpuesto(textLink)};


                   var tdLink = document.createElement("td");

                   tdLink.appendChild(Link);

                   tr.appendChild(tdLink);

                 tabla.appendChild(tr);

               }


             }


 function eliminarImpuesto(element)
 {
    //getting it back...
    var i = element.getAttribute('data-i');
 }
```

Comment: Already solved it settingn the link.id = i then in the parameter this.id

Comment: Glad to know you made it!